# Doctrine 2, Custom strip xss filter?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

So I have been trying to implement a generic solution for stripping XSS injections before going to the view.

This works great ( for arrays, simple object and strings )

```
$this->view->assign('data', '<script>alert("test")</script>');
$this->view->assign('data', array(0 => '..xss attack ...'));
```

But doctrine has lazy loading, meaning in the view you don't get filtering for Doctrine records that the lazy loader fetched. in such that:

```
$this->view->assign('result', $this->model->getAllUsers());
```

And in the view:

```
// Here comes the problem.
foreach($result as $user){
    foreach($user->getComments() as $comment){

    }
}
```

**Question**

Is there any way to hydrate or apply custom a filter that uses htmlentites() function when assigning value to object ?

**Solutions so far**

- Hydrate to array before assigning to the view, but not a good idea when I want to have my custom methods.
- Use escape function on every single "echo" output ( echo $this->stripXSS($obj->getName() ) anyway, this is not secure, you might forget that and it's not really a good idea for generic solution.

Here is the function I have created for stripping XSS injections. ( its applied on assign() )

```
/**
     * Recursive method.
     *
     * Can remove XSS attacks from both strings and arrays.
     * Uses htmlentities, ENT_QUOTES , UTF-8
     * 
     * @param mixed $var A variable to strip for XSS attacks.
     */
    public function stripXSS($var){
        // Well this was easy, lets escape that shall we ?
        if (is_string($var))return htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

        // This is a array, here we can need recursive...
        if (is_array($var)){
            foreach($var as $k => $v){
                // $v can be array too, and any type for that case ... so .. make it call itself.
                $var[$k] = $this->stripXSS($v);
            }
            // Return the array.
            return $var;
        // Exceptions assigned is not clonable, skip it.
        }else if (is_object($var) && !($var instanceof \Exception) && !($var instanceof \Closure)){
            // Use reflection to set properties.


            if (!method_exists($var, '__clone')){
                // Clone it, we don't want anything to change except in the VIEW...
                $var = clone $var;

                // Get its properties..
                $ref = new \ReflectionObject($var);
                $props = $ref->getProperties();
                foreach($props as $prop){
                    $prop->setAccessible(true);
                    $val = $prop->getValue($var);
                    if (is_string($val) || is_array($val) || is_object($val)){
                        $prop->setValue($var, $this->stripXSS($val));
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        // Well, this is either a int, float and so fourth - meaning it does not need to be escaped. Return.
        return $var;
    }
```

Comment: I think you should filter the strings before the model/entity/whatever be persisted

Comment: Escaping data such as HTML before persisting it to the database seems like a bad solution to a problem. What if the data is used in another application, parsers is then needed to encode it to HTML. Also this adds domain logic to business logic. I think i'm better off creating a normal function out("Data") or something rather then the use of echo.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter  every property (or string property) of doctrine entity just before flushing the entity object after change, You can use Doctrine`s preFlush hook for that, You just have to write 10 lines of code and it will apply on all entities. Follow this post- [Prevent XSS (ZendFramework & Doctrine 2)](http://viveksoni.net/prevent-xss-zend-framework-2-and-doctrine-2-stack/)

Comment: link is dead, some code would have made that answer more util